# Unreal Engine Perforce Synchronization issue

Tags: version-control, perforce, unreal-engine4

So we're trying to get perforce source control running with UE4. We can see checked out files and change history but changes in blueprint are only visible after Editor Restart which is quite counter productive and irritating for developers.

I'd try to explain scenario:

P1 opens project and connects to source control. P2 opens project and connects to source control.

P1 checks out a blueprint and makes some changes. then P1 checks in the blueprint back to source control.

Now P2 wants to make some changes to that blueprint. P2 refreshes the blueprint sees exclaimation mark (showing file need to be synced). P2 Synchronizes the file and refreshes now blueprint has no mark on it showing file not synchronized. But when P2 opens blueprint it is same as before, P2 can't see changes made by other person. P2 has to restart editor to see changes in effect.

Please help us out on this.

Comment: Try to post this in answerhub's Bug Report section, this is obviously a bug-like problem. Post there and you'll get an answer soon. https://answers.unrealengine.com/

Comment: By the way, we have the same problem, but I always restart the editor. If you feel restarting is too slow, try to get a SSD :P

Comment: I was going through documentation and there they have specifically mentioned Epic prefers Restarting editor. So I think this is the way we'll have to follow. p.s. I am using SSD ;) Problem for us is Flow.

Comment: Got it, hope your work flow goes well!